# How to get totalhits from Query

Tags: symfony, pagination, elasticsearch, elastica

I want to get the total results for a query using elastica for symfony2
what I did :

```
$u = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.documents_index.documents');
$maxItems=10;
$query = new \Elastica\Query\Bool();
$elasticaQuery = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString($key_words.'~');
$elasticaQuery->setFuzzyPrefixLength(3);
$query->addMust($elasticaQuery);
try {
        $q = new \Elastica\Query();
        $q->setQuery($query);
        $q->setFrom(($page - 1) * $maxItems);
    } 
catch (Exception $e) {
        }
$data = $u->find($q);
```

$data is always 10 documents but this is not the problem , the problem is how to get the total hits so I can use them in Pagination :)

Answer (score 0):

The Elastica\ResultSet class has a method called getTotalHits() so you can do something like this after the search and get the full record count for totals/pagination/etc:

```
$hits = $resultSet->getTotalHits();
```

See source code here: [Elastica ResultSet Class](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/blob/master/lib/Elastica/ResultSet.php).

As an aside, the Elastica source code is incredibly well-structured and easy to read which more than makes up for it's lack of documentation. Well worth reading both the source and the unit tests if you get stuck.

Comment: find and search don't return a resultSet